# Host multiple PowerShell versions

Tags: .net, powershell

On [this page](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/powershell/archive/2013/10/31/paap-windows-powershell-as-a-platform-part-2.aspx) the PowerShell team shows how to host the PowerShell engine in your .NET application, and to pass commands to it.

Is there any way to control which version of the PowerShell engine is created?  Maybe use v2 for one script, and v4 for another?

I would have thought the InitialSessionState.Create method would enable it, but it doesn't appear to be the case.

Answer (score -1):

I made a quick function for you to execute a ScriptBlock in a job with a powershell 2.0

```
Function Execute-Job ([scriptblock]$ScriptBlock, [array]$ArgumentList, [switch]$PassThru, [switch]$PS2) {


    If ($PS2) { $Job = Start-Job -ScriptBlock $ScriptBlock -ArgumentList $ArgumentList -PSVersion 2.0 }
         Else { $Job = Start-Job -ScriptBlock $ScriptBlock -ArgumentList $ArgumentList }

    If ($PassThru) { $Job | Receive-Job -Wait -AutoRemoveJob } 
              Else { $Job }

} #End Function Execute-Job

$ScriptBlock = { $PSVersionTable }
Execute-Job $ScriptBlock -PassThru -Ps2
```

This return:

```
Name                           Value                                                                                                                                                                                                
----                           -----                                                                                                                                                                                                
PSRemotingProtocolVersion      2.1                                                                                                                                                                                                  
BuildVersion                   6.1.7601.17514                                                                                                                                                                                       
PSCompatibleVersions           {1.0, 2.0}                                                                                                                                                                                           
PSVersion                      2.0          <----------                                                                                                                                                                                                 
CLRVersion                     2.0.50727.5485                                                                                                                                                                                       
WSManStackVersion              2.0                                                                                                                                                                                                  
SerializationVersion           1.1.0.1
```

Tell me what you think! ;)

Comment: Posted to TechNet: https://gallery.technet.microsoft.com/Function-Execute-Job-c2f76200

Comment: That's nice, but isn't what we're after.  We need a .NET app to be able to send a script to a PS 2 and also PS 3 (or PS 4) engine, all within the same app.

Comment: I thought my code was cute.. :P Ok, so your PS script is embedded inside your .NET app, so your not calling powershell.exe directly to execute. Right?

Comment: I should get a point just for how damn cute my code was.. no? :P